# Predicate logic for Containment

Tags: c#, predicate

Please help me out with correct logic for predicate.

I have some list of products that i want to show in some regions that user specifies.

My Product class is next:

```
 public class Product
 {
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public List<string> regions { get; set; }
 }
```

And my settings class is:

```
public class LocalSettings
{
    public List<string> Regions { get; set; }
}
```

So the logic is next if user selected Region, for example, Europe then all Products with  "`public List<string> regions`" containing Europe must be selected.

How should i write this in predicate correctly?

Here is my start point:

```
Predicate<Product> ProductFinder = (Product p) => { return DataManager.Instance.CurrentSettings.Regions.Contains(//HERE MUST BE ANY OF p.regions); };
```

Edit Question Number 1:

Thanks to help i have wrote this:

```
Predicate<Salesplay> SalesPlaysFinder = (Salesplay p) => { return DataManager.Instance.CurrentSettings.Regions.Intersect(p.regions).Any(); };
```

but my p.regions is a List i need to convert it to string

can i do something like .Intersect(p.regions.ToString()?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your question, you could use the [`Any`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.any.aspx) and [`Contains`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.contains.aspx) methods like this:

```
Predicate<Product> ProductFinder = p => 
    DataManager.Instance.CurrentSettings.Regions.Any(r => p.regions.Contains(r))
```

Or you could use the [`Intersect`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.intersect.aspx) and  [`Any`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.any.aspx) methods like this:

```
Predicate<Product> ProductFinder = p => 
    DataManager.Instance.CurrentSettings.Regions.Intersect(p.regions).Any()
```

---

For your updated question, if you want to test if a single string in the list, just use [`Contains`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.contains.aspx) by itself:

```
Predicate<Salesplay> SalesplayFinder = p => 
    DataManager.Instance.CurrentSettings.Regions.Contains(p.region)
```

Comment: You should remove the type name from the lambda argument.

Comment: @Magus Yeah good point. That's inferred from the the variable declaration.

Comment: sorry for bothering, but how can i make a convertion in lambda expression?
See my edit of a question number 1

Comment: @Cheese I'm not sure I understand what you're asking. This *is* a lambda expression.

Comment: look at my edit of a my question now. You understood my question correctly =). I', still working on my English

Comment: Now you haven't understood me, but i have changed my public List<object> regions { get; set; } to public List<string> regions { get; set; } in Product class and your code worked perfectly, thanks, you helped me out.

Comment: @Cheese Ahh, I see. You could use `...Intersect(p.regions.Select(o => o.ToString()).Any()` or similar.